# In edit mode, how to move a given vertex or group of vertices by a specified value?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I would like to be able to type in a value when moving or rotating a selected vertex or group of vertices. When using the Transform panel, the whole object moves. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Have you gone to Editmode and typed ```G``` or ```R``` when your vertex is selected?

Comment: Yes that was it. I added more details in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to tweak the value in the pop up window that appears when you press the move or rotate buttons on the side:

[image]

Another way is to press <kbd>G</kbd> for grab or  <kbd>R</kbd> for rotate, then press <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> to constrain the move or rotation to an axis, and then type your value which appears in the top left corner. Backspace also works.

[image]

You don't need to constrain the value. Typing only <kbd>G</kbd> or <kbd>R</kbd> and then typing the <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> values separated by a kbd>Tab also works.